# How to fetch commit messages from bitbucket for project manager to see

Tags: project-management, version-control

Is it possible to fetch commit messages from bitbucket via json or something so that a project manager can see what the changes are without having to look at the code. If it's possible can you give me some ideas on how to do it.

Comment: bitbucket has an API, did you check it?

Comment: If all you want are commit messages (and you are indeed ok with an "or something" rather than "json"), and you are set on using a user interface for this, why both with an API when you can use `hg log` or `git log` / `git shortlog`??

Comment: Furthermore, if the project manager is non-technical, I doubt commit messages will be interesting. More likely, the manage would be interested in seeing the tickets (which you can also fetch via an API), which you obviously reference in all your commits (you do, do you?). If the project manager is technical, I'd say the hg/git command line or GUI client would do, as I suggested in the previous comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned by Yannis in his comment, you can use the [Bitbucket API](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Using+the+bitbucket+REST+APIs).

The [documentation for changesets](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Changesets) says that you can use the following URI to get a list of all changesets for a repository:

https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/USERNAME/REPOSITORY/changesets

For example, https://api.bitbucket.org/1.0/repositories/jespern/django-piston/changesets
*(this is the example link from the documentation)*

This *does* return JSON, but I doubt that this is really comfortable to read for a (non-technical?) manager.

**--> I guess I'd rather give him the link to [the list of commits in Bitbucket's GUI](https://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/changesets).

IMO it's much easier to read and he doesn't need to look at the code either.**